# Filter a Magento collection

Tags: php, magento, collections, where-clause

I would like to filter a collection with grouped clauses. In SQL this would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE col1='x' AND (col2='y' OR (col2='z' and col4='P' and col5='q') OR (col2='x' and col4='r'))
```

How can I "translate" this to filtering a collection with 
-> `addFieldToFilter(...)`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your query was similar to

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE col1='x' AND (col2='y' OR col2='z' OR col4='P')
```

You could use following:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('col1', 'x')->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
         array('attribute'=>'col2', 'eq'=>'y'),
         array('attribute'=>'col2', 'eq'=>'z'),
         array('attribute' => 'col4', 'eq' => 'P')
    )
)
```

But in your case for such complex query You should use Zend_Db_Select